# Moving discussion in comments to chat

Tags: discussion

[This Question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/20347/8755) has recently attracted a long string of comments which appears to be discussion that ought really to be in chat.

One commenter has used a sequence of four or so comments to provide space for a lengthy exposition of their (mostly unsubstantiated) opinion on the topic.

I'm not advocating suppressing dissenting opinions but I worry that the commenter is merely using one answer to the question as a convenient peg on which to hang his or her lengthy essay on the subject. I feel the comments are not really helpful to anyone trying to improve the answer by editing it. Expanding the answer to cover the subject of holocaust denial might lead to a rather lengthy answer that few would read and stimulate further unhelpful commentary.

Can, and should, these comments be removed from the answer they are attached to and placed in chat instead? Perhaps there can be a comment linking to the relevant section of chat containing the content?

Comment: Did you flag it?

Comment: @SKlivvz: I have now. I've also copied the refs in the comments to a footnote in my answer with the aim of preserving the main useful material from comments. I previously added a comment suggesting to the main commenter  that they create their own answer based on their comments.

Answer (score 1):

As you have taken the most relevant links, those which actually improved on the answer, and added them to your answer I have removed all comments.

The same action would probably have been taken by simply flagging the answer with a relevant comment, but thanks for bringing to our attention.